# In Java, from where can a constructor be invoked?

Tags: java

Is this statement true or false?

"The only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor."

I thought a constructor could be invoked from within a method (and other places) if the call to the constructor is preceded with the keyword 'new'.

How about this statement? True or false?

"The only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor (using a call to super() or this()), or from within static or instance methods, static or instance initializer blocks, or even constructors, if the call to the constructor is preceded by the keyword 'new'." Trying to invoke a constructor like you would invoke a method (using only its name) is not allowed."

Is this more accurate? "Where the call to the constructor is not preceded by the keyword 'new', the only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor using this() or super() as the first statement."

Comment: Is this is a trick question?

Comment: The answer is: it depends on what we mean by invoking a constructor. And by another constructor.

Comment: @biziclop Invocation has a JLS-specific definition.

Comment: @chrylis - But we don't know how the author of the quoted statements is using the term "invoke" according to that definition, or some other definition or .... loosely.

Comment: Not a trick question. I read it in a book.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just go straight to the [JLS, §8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8):

> Constructors are invoked by class instance creation expressions (§15.9), by the conversions and concatenations caused by the string concatenation operator + (§15.18.1), and by explicit constructor invocations from other constructors (§8.8.7). [...]
>
> Constructors are never invoked by method invocation expressions (§15.12).

Therefore, the first statement you quoted is technically false, as the JLS defines using `new` as invoking the constructor.

Note that your paragraph-length statement is a combination of true and false information; you can't invoke a constructor from static or instance methods except via creating a new object.

Comment: So are you saying that string concatenation is just a constructor invocation? Rather than an operation that involves invoking a constructor? I think you're being misled by the "invoked by" phrase.

Comment: @biziclop I said no such thing; I quoted the JLS verbatim. String concatenation, however, *can*, depending whether the expression is a compile-time constant, result in the compiler's producing bytecode that is the equivalent of creating a `new StringBuilder()`.

Comment: That's what I'm getting at. Your argument is perfectly valid but there is a semantic difference between explicitly invoking a constructor (which you can only do from another constructor) or indirectly invoking a constructor (which can be done by all the things you listed). Which one did the author of the question mean? Only they know.

Comment: @biziclop *Invoked* has a defined meaning. If the professor asking the question meant something else, then he needs to provide an alternate definition. When using terms with specific definitions, those are assumed unless the speaker makes a point of deviating.

Comment: You mean this: `Constructors (§8.8) are similar to methods, but cannot be invoked directly by a method call`?

Comment: Is this more accurate? "Where the call to the constructor is not preceded by the keyword 'new', the only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor using this() or super() as the first statement."

Answer (score 2):

Rather than focusing on what the author of the original questions means by "invoke"<sup>1</sup>, here are the different ways that a constructor will be called.

- By using the `new` operator with the class name and parameters that match the constructor signature:

  ```
      Foon f = new Foon(1, 2);
  ```

  It is also possible to do the same thing using reflection and the `Constructor` object equivalent to a `new` expression, or by using the relevant JNI or JNA callbacks in native code equivalent to a `new` expression.  However, in all cases, the constructor invocation is conceptually happening at same point in the object creation.  Hence I will treat them as identical.
- By explicitly chaining to the constructor from another constructor in the same class using `this(...)`.
- By explicitly chaining to the constructor from a direct subclass constructor using `super(...)`, or by implicitly chaining to a no-args constructor via an implied `super()` in a direct subclass constructor (declared or implied).

  The implicit cases are merely "syntactic sugar" for the explicit `super` chaining cases.

---

There are a few other places where `new` is invoked behind the scenes by Java from regular Java code.  A couple that spring to mind are string concatenation, auto-boxing, and the JVM throwing certain exceptions; e.g.

```
    null.toString()   // implicitly creates a NullPointerException obj.
```

---

<sup>1 - ... which is unknowable unless we understand the context, including how the OP's lecturer (or text book) is using the word "invoke".</sup>

Comment: Partially correct, but the JLS also specifically points out string concatenation and boxing.

Comment: But it does that using `new` or equivalent.  Hence covered by one of the other bullets.

Comment: Only if you are going to say that "or equivalent" means `invokespecial <init>`, in which *that* is the only way to invoke the constructor. The bytecode for all of the methods boils down to that instruction, but there's no "hidden" or intermediate `new` call for concatenation or boxing; from the perspective *of the Java language*, they're multiple paths to generating the same bytecode, which is a JVMS implementation detail.

Comment: @chrylis - please write your own answer.  It is probably more constructive than telling other people how you >would< answer.

Comment: Besides, you are most likely incorrect about the way that reflection and JNI / JNI work.  They will not be executing an `invokespecial` instruction.  They will be doing something that is equivalent to what `invokespecial` does.  (I only say "most likely" because I have not deep-dived the OpenJDK source code to check this.)

Answer (score 0):

**It's true**. You can't write code that actually calls a constructor as follows:

```
class Vehicle {
    Vehicle() { } // Constructor
    void doSomething() {
        Vehicle(); // Illegal
    }
}
```

Comment: This in itself is no proof: `Vehicle()` would be nonsense in any context. If you replace it with `this()` however, then we're getting somewhere.

Comment: I agree with that piece of code, but the statement says a statement can be invoked ONLY from within another constructor. And I know I can invoke a constructor using 'new' from another method like main(). It seems like the statement at issue, "The only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor," is therefore too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

The famous illusive constructor.
It's there when it's there, and even when it's not there it's still  there.

The constructor is called at object creation.

So yeah the constructor can, or more precisely will be called if you create a object using **new** , na matter where you use it.

That quote of yours seems to be incomplete

> "The only way the constructor of the superclass of the current class can be invoked is from within the current class constructor."

Comment: I'm primarily focused on this statement: "The only way a constructor can be invoked is from within another constructor." I know that I can invoke a constructor from main() if my call to the constructor is preceded by 'new', which is not 'another constructor.'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor when you use the class as an object in other class.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, directly invoking another constructor of the same object using the `this(...)` or `super(...)` construct (called `explicit constructor invocation`), the answer is [yes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1).

It is probable that this is what the question meant but you have to be really precise in the wording and this question isn't.

Because if by "invoke" you mean, "causing a constructor to run", then you can "invoke" a constructor with the `new` keyword, which first allocates and creates the object, and then a constructor is run. In this, rather looser sense the answer is no.

But, importantly, `new` does a lot more than just calling the constructor. So in the most literal sense, calling `new` is not the same as invoking a constructor. Just like making tea involves pouring hot water but is not the same as simply pouring hot water.

Whether you want to make that distinction or not is up to you, or in this case the author of the question, you need to ask them.

Comment: Thanks, biziclop. The statement came out of a book and they probably meant it in the more restrictive sense, but the way it was written it has a much more expansive interpretation. "The only way a constructor can be invoked") is pretty narrow. I think it should have been qualified.

Answer (score 0):

***This statement is false.***

'Invoking a constructor' can mean three different things:

1. You can invoke a constructor by creating a new object with the `new` operator:

   ```
   String s = new String("abc");
   ```

   In which case you will first allocate an object and then invoke the constructor:

   ```
   NEW java/lang/String // allocate String instance
   LDC "abc"            // push the String constant on the stack
   INVOKESPECIAL "java/lang/String"."<init>" : "(Ljava/lang/String;)V" // invoke constructor
   ```
2. The second way is to invoke another constructor from the same class:

   ```
   class Super
   {
       Super(int i) { }
   }
   class Test extends Super {
       Test() { this(1); }
       // Bytecode:
          INVOKESPECIAL "Test"."<init>" : "(I)V"
       // ---------
   ```
3. The third way to invoke a constructor is to invoke one from the super class:

   ```
       Test(int i) { super(i); }
       // Bytecode:
          INVOKESPECIAL "Super"."<init>" : "(I)V"
       // ---------
   }
   ```

Either way, the generated bytecode will contain an `INVOKESPECIAL` instruction. This means you are literally invoking the constructor in *three* cases, so if you define 'invoke' by that instruction, there is more than one way to invoke a constructor.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the bytecode of `new`  will only contain a single `invokespecial` instruction?

Comment: Yes, unless you pass a constructor call as an argument: `new Wrapper(new Object())` - I have been working on JVM compilers for long enough to know my bytecodes.

Comment: Cos I just wonder what the `new` bytecode does then. :) When do you think that code is being used?

Comment: I added some bytecode examples (in pseudocode) to clear this up.